# Trying to get valid time from excel xml file into OpenOfficeCalc

Tags: xml, excel, openoffice-calc

The xml file is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet" ?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" >
<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" />
<Styles >
<Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal" >
<Borders />
<Interior />
<NumberFormat />
<Protection />
<Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
<Font />
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s21" >
<NumberFormat ss:Format="dd\/MM\/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
</Style>
<Style ss:ID="s23" >
<NumberFormat ss:Format="0.00000" />
</Style>
</Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1" >
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="5" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1040" >
<Row >
<Cell >
<Data ss:Type="String" >Date</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell >
<Data ss:Type="String" >Open</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell >
<Data ss:Type="String" >Close</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell >
<Data ss:Type="String" >High</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell >
<Data ss:Type="String" >Low</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row >
<Cell ss:StyleID="s21" >
<Data ss:Type="DateTime" >2016-07-02T02:49:00</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s23" >
<Data ss:Type="Number" >0.74900</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s23" >
<Data ss:Type="Number" >0.74800</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s23" >
<Data ss:Type="Number" >0.74900</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s23" >
<Data ss:Type="Number" >0.74800</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
```

etc

The result in Open Office Calc comes out like this:-

```
Date                Open    Close   High    Low
02/07/2016 00:00:00 0.74900 0.74800 0.74900 0.74800
02/07/2016 00:00:00 0.74900 0.75000 0.75000 0.74900
01/07/2016 00:00:00 0.74800 0.74900 0.74900 0.74800
01/07/2016 00:00:00 0.74700 0.74800 0.74800 0.74700
01/07/2016 00:00:00 0.74600 0.74700 0.74700 0.74600
01/07/2016 00:00:00 0.74500 0.74600 0.74600 0.74500
```

Note the time is always 00:00:00 but the xml file contains the correct time.

I can only alter the xml file or change settings in Open Office Calc

So What can I change to get the correct time value to appear in Open Office Calc??

nb: I have "Note Tab Light" which allows me to use regex so modifying the xml file is practical.

Many Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

If `OpenOffice` or `LibreOffice` try importing XML files which are different from their own XML, then they are using XML import filters. You can set those filters via `Tools - XML Filter Settings`.

The default import filter for `MS Excel 2003 XML` contains the following XSLT:

```
            <xsl:when test="ss:Data/@ss:Type = 'DateTime'">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="(contains( $data-format, 'Date') or contains($data-format,'y') or contains($data-format,'g') or contains($data-format,'d') or contains($data-format,'e') or starts-with( substring( ss:Data, 11), 'T00:00:00.000' ) ) and (not (contains( $data-format, 'Time') ) )">
                        <xsl:attribute name="office:value-type">date</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="office:date-value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(ss:Data, 'T')"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:attribute name="office:value-type">time</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="office:time-value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('P',substring(ss:Data, 11, 3), 'H', substring(ss:Data, 15, 2), 'M', substring(ss:Data, 18,2), 'S')"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
```

That means the filter takes **either** the date part **or** the time part but not both.

One could change the XSLT like:

```
            <xsl:when test="ss:Data/@ss:Type = 'DateTime'">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="(contains( $data-format, 'Date') or contains($data-format,'y') or contains($data-format,'g') or contains($data-format,'d') or contains($data-format,'e') or starts-with( substring( ss:Data, 11), 'T00:00:00.000' ) ) and (not (contains( $data-format, 'Time') ) )">
                        <xsl:attribute name="office:value-type">date</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="office:date-value">
                        <!--    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(ss:Data, 'T')"/> -->
                            <xsl:value-of select="ss:Data"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:attribute name="office:value-type">time</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="office:time-value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('P',substring(ss:Data, 11, 3), 'H', substring(ss:Data, 15, 2), 'M', substring(ss:Data, 18,2), 'S')"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
```

But for that one must change `share\xslt\import\spreadsheetml\spreadsheetml2ooo.xsl` in all OpenOffice Applications which are supposed to import that `MS Excel 2003 XML`. So this is not practicable.

One could hope that Apache will correct the default import filter for `MS Excel 2003 XML`. But will they?

So in conclusion is to say that it is currently not possible to get `DateTime` from `MS Excel 2003 XML` to `OpenOffice`.

But `MS Excel 2003 XML` is rather old. Why do you need using this old XML? Why not simply using real Excel fromats like `BIFF` (`*.xls`)  or `Office OpenXML` (`*.xlsx`)?